# Setup external hard drive?

Tags: release-loki, system-installation, pantheon-files, disk-management

So I have an extra external hard drive that I was using for my xbox.  So I'm trying to set it up so i have extra space for apps and files for my elementary installation.

I installed gparted so i could delete it and setup a new partition, but I think im doing something wrong.

can someone hook me up with a little step by step that would give me instructions on how to set this up and get it going?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would check out this instructional post.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/315914/step-by-step-guide-to-partition-an-external-hdd-in-two-file-formats

Seems to have a lot of information along with step by step instructions including screenshots on the use of gparted. I would be aware though, monkeying with the partitions has its risks and I would suggest making a backup of your xbox data elsewere so you don't loose your saved 'Banjo Kazooie' files ;) .

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.  that helped.  the big key though was tracking down that when all is said and done, that i should `sudo chmod -R 777 /media/christian/External` so that I can use it.

thanks again